# Vertical smooth scroll with snap effect on the next or previous section

Tags: javascript

I need help replicating this https://swiper-master.webflow.io/full-page-vertical in pure vanilla js. I cannot figure out how to implement this. Kindly assist.

Expected output, smooth scroll from one section to the next either upwards or downwards based on mouse scroll or keyboard arrow down up keys.

I have 6 sections in my html, but I want to target only the first 3 sections with this animation shown in this link https://swiper-master.webflow.io/full-page-vertical then the rest of the sections should just scroll "normal" without the scroll snap effect.

```
<div>
    <section data-section="section1">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Content for section 1 goes here.</p>
    </section>
    <section data-section="section2">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Content for section 2 goes here.</p>
    </section>
    <section data-section="section3">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Content for section 3 goes here.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <p>Content for section 4 goes here.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 5</h2>
        <p>Content for section 5 goes here.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 6</h2>
        <p>Content for section 6 goes here.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
const winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const pages = document.querySelectorAll("[data-section]");
  let currentPage = 0;

  window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function (e) {
    scrollPages(e.wheelDelta);
  });
  window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    scrollPages(-1 * e.detail);
  });

  function scrollPages(delta) {
    const direction = delta > 0 ? "up" : "down";
    const currentPageOffset = currentPage * winHeight;

    if (direction == "down" && currentPage <= pages.length - 2) {
      // scroll into view centered
      window.scrollTo({
        top: currentPageOffset + winHeight,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
      currentPage++;
    } else if (direction == "up" && currentPage > 0) {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: currentPageOffset - winHeight,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
      currentPage--;
    }
  }
```

This however does not really give the intended scroll snap output whenever mouse or arrow is used, scroll immediately to the next/previous section.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free code writing service. Have a look at [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NasserKessas The question been updated with some code, thanks.

Comment: Do you have any CSS?

Comment: I have not setup any CSS for this, is it possible to do it with pure JS?

Comment: No, for example, you'll need CSS to make each section the size of the full screen. I'll also make animations much easier as you could use the CSS animation property.

Comment: I see, I have setup this pen here: https://codepen.io/robertkibet/pen/gOjrXWd let me know if you can access it. I have added the css for section height also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250746/discussion-between-nasser-kessas-and-bizman).